# ListView.builder() in Flutter with different items

Tags: dart, flutter, material-design

Consider the following `build()` function:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: 6,
              itemBuilder: (context, i){
                if(numberTruthList[i]){
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Text("$i"),
                  );
                }
              },
          ),
        )
      ),
    );
  }
```

If the numberTruthList is

`List<bool> numberTruthList = [true, true, true, true , true, true];`

then the output comes out to be

[image]

and if the numberTruthList is

`List<bool> numberTruthList = [false, true, true, true , true, true];`

the output comes out to be

[image]

I want the output to be a ListView with the items

```
 ListTile( title: Text("$i"),);
```

for values of i such that numberTruthList[i] is true, what should be the code?

Comment: https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/lists/mixed-list

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: 6,
  itemBuilder: (context, i) {
    return numberTruthList[i]
      ? ListTile(
          title: Text(numberTruthList[i].toString()),
        )
      : Container(
          height: 0,
          width: 0,
        );
   },
)
```

Comment: there is a huge gap at the space of empty ListTiles. How do I remove that?

Comment: This huge gap is empty `ListTile()`. Replace it with `Container` has 0 height and 0 width.

Answer (score 1):

use `Wrap()` in else case.

`Container` wraps content when there is content and match parent when there are no content.

`Wrap` wraps the content no matter what.

Answer (score 0):

The `itemBuilder` should always return a non-null `Widget`. You can check it [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView/ListView.builder.html).

Answer (score 0):

In the body, we have ListView.builder with itemcount 20 and itemBuilder which will create a new widget again and again up to 20 times because we have itemCount=20. If we don't use itemCount in ListView.builder then we will get infinite list items so it is recommended to use itemCount to avoid such mistakes.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const int itemCount = 20;

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: itemCount,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return ListTile(
          title: Text('Contact ${(index + 1)}'),
          leading: const Icon(Icons.person_outline_rounded),
          trailing: const Icon(Icons.select_all_rounded),
          onTap: () {
            debugPrint('Contact ${(index + 1)}');
          },
        );
      }
    );
  }
}
```